# How do I improve my tracking while flipping?

Tags: gymnastics

I have been attempting to get the hang of various flips off of the diving board into the pool. One of the problems I run into is that I'm very bad at tracking where I am in a flip so as to know when to pull out for the landing. It's possibly complicated by the fact that I'm over a relatively trackless surface (the water) and I'm pretty much forced to do the flips without my glasses (I'm myopic with a fair amount of astigmatism), but I suspect that, as much as anything, I'm just not keeping track of where I am very well. It just all goes by so fast from jump to spinning to landing.

Are there any tricks to improving tracking? Repeated attempts don't seem to be bearing much fruit, as I'm getting a consistent timing, but not one that's well-suited to adapting if distances change (such as with a new swimming pool) or being able to adapt my technique for a new move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to obtain prescription swim goggles in order to spot the surface of the water (or other visual reference points) more accurately.

> Many divers think that simply “feeling” the dive in the air is enough, but in order to dive consistently, you must learn how to spot. For most, learning to spot is a challenge, but there are some tricks you can use to help you pick up your spots and learn this important skill.

Read more at: http://diving.isport.com/diving-guides/how-to-visually-spot-in-diving